# Why does PowerShell's Install-Module fail for Posh-Git?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, git

I have just tried installing Posh-Git from the PowerShell gallery by copy and pasting this command:

```
Install-Module -Name posh-git -RequiredVersion 0.7.1
```

The command seems to run fine, i.e. there is a slight delay, and my PowerShell prompt returns. There are no success or error messages, yet I still don't have the special Posh-Git prompt in Git folders, and the `C:\Users\brady\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` folder is empty, implying no module was installed.

As suggested, using the `-verbose` switch gave the following output:

```
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='posh-git'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'posh-git'.
VERBOSE: Skipping installed module posh-git 0.7.1.
```

Then checking the `$error` variable gave the following output:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PowerShellGet.Telemetry].
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:715 char:26
+ ... yMethods = ([Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PowerShellGet.Telemetry] | ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...llGet.Telemetry:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: Did you try to run it with the `-verbose` option? Did that give you any more information? Did you check `$error` manually?

Comment: @Seth I have now and included the output in my OP.

Comment: Could you try to remove the model (with `verbose`) and install it again (with `verbose`)? As you can see by the output, currently it's assuming that `posh-git 0.7.1` is installed. Did you try to search for `posh-git` on your system?

Comment: I uninstalled the module, which in found somewhere in program files, and re-installed it. The second install worked, but posh-git is still no giving me its special git prompt.

Comment: Did you import the module? Did you check the [requirements and check what the prompt is set to](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you do not meet Posh-Git's [Requirements](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#prerequisites) or you did not import Posh-Git using `Import-Module`

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\code\Office365> #See no special git info
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\code\Office365> Import-Module posh-git
C:\Users\user\Documents\code\Office365 [develop ↑1 +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

Comment: I didn't use `Import-Module`. Once I use it, everything is fine. Last time I just installed it and it worked. How do I now get PS to import the module every-time I start it?

Comment: You can have it import automatically if you put the import statement in your PS profile. Easiest way to get there is to run something like Ise $profile or if you use vscode code $profile